# Test uniformity after adding some non-uniform data in python

Tags: distributions, p-value, uniform-distribution, scipy

I generate `N1` numbers from uniform distribution using `numpy` python package from a certain interval e.g., `[low,high]` and combine with some non-uniform numbers from the same interval which can be repeated

> Because I have only `54` unique predefined numbers between `[low,high]` and pull out numbers from this data which are not generate from any uniform distribution. They are generate from some [chaotic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_chaotic_maps).

Now, I test the uniformity of this resultant data:

```py
data = np.concatenate((nonuniform_data, np.random.uniform(low, high, [N1])))
_stats, p = scipy_stats.kstest(data, scipy_stats.uniform(loc=low, scale=high - low).cdf)
# p -> 0.5287917616633173
```

And the `p-value` is always between `0-1` as expected. But to guarantee the null hypothesis (the mixed data follow or come from uniform distribution) [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/547845/270559) suggest to check "do the p-values come from a uniform distribution?"

I run the kstest (Kolmogorov–Smirnov test) for `2000` times to get `p-values` and plot the `p-values`:

[image]

which seems quite uniform,

```py
_stats, p = scipy_stats.kstest(p_values, scipy_stats.uniform(loc=0, scale=1).cdf)
# p -> 6.80874492574208e-07
```

But to guarantee the uniformity of this mixture data the `p-values` itself should be uniform distribution on `[0,1]` every time. Hence, change the mixture number `N1` and apply kstest for different values of `N1`. Running the test for different `N1` values with default significance level `0.1` using this [code](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/547841/270559):

$$
\begin{array} {|r|r|}
 \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{KS test for p-values}} & \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{# of non-uniform data}}
& \style{font-family:inherit}{\text{# of uniform data}}\\
\hline (0.5858507235230785, True) & 50 &  2450  \\
\hline (0.936998704584743, True) &100 & 9900 \\
\hline (0.416989754218446, True) & 150 & 22350 \\
\hline (0.05388683955413753, False) & 200 & 39800 \\
\hline (0.02358711070174885, False) & 250 & 62250 \\
\hline (0.1055808992463183, True) & 300&  89700 \\
\hline (0.008437370587141033, False)&  350&  122150 \\
\hline (0.0017850674918899055, False)&  400 & 159600 \\
\hline (0.0004156878457119884, False)&  450&  202050 \\
\hline (0.001655399708003342, False)&  500 & 249500 \\
\hline (0.00036075938599595237, False)&  550&  301950 \\
\hline (0.0014847547840858462, False) & 600&  359400 \\
\hline (0.00039739769639024827, False)&  650&  421850 \\
\hline (0.0002500280144076814, False)&  700&  489300 \\
\hline (9.236813390614254e^{-05}, False)& 750&  561750 \\
\hline (1.8224958240829835e^{-05}, False) & 800 & 639200 \\
\hline (6.3006801226360525e^{-06}, False) & 850&  721650 \\
\hline (2.7592718787751226e^{-06}, False)&  900&  809100 \\
\hline (2.46888962111129e^{-07}, False) &950& 901550 \\
\hline (1.739925789055794e^{-07}, False)& 1000 &999000\\
\hline  \end{array}
$$

I was wondering, why the `p_values` not pass the kstest. As I increase the uniform data compare to non-uniform data in every case. Is there any ratio rule $\left(\frac{\text{non-uniform data}}{\text{uniform data}}\right)$ which can guarantee the mixture data is always pass the uniformity test or seem generated from uniform distribution?

Comment: It is very difficult to understand what you are doing or asking.  Are you perhaps misinterpreting low p-values as being *not* significant?

Comment: I was thinking the p-values should be uniform for null hypothesis from [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/10613/270559) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/547845/270559). Do low p-values also mean significant in my case? Sorry, I am not super familiar with statistics. I was trying to understand **how much** non-uniform data are **allowed** to mixture with uniform data to make it **still uniform** @whuber. Do I need to add more details? Please let me know if that's case.

Comment: As far as I understand this, your underlying distribution is *not* uniform, so on what basis do you expect the p-values of a uniformity test to be uniform?

Comment: I pull a small number of data from the underlying distribution and mixture with a large data from uniform distribution. I was guessing adding the small perturbation won't change the distribution of the larger data.  @ChristianHennig

Comment: Now, I just want to know in what proportion should I mixture to guarantee the mixed data should be uniform @ChristianHennig

Comment: A small perturbation will obviously also perturb uniformity of the p-value, albeit only to a small extent. With bigger datasets even a small change of the distribution will normally lead to a clear non-uniformity of the p-value (obviously it depends on how exactly your perturbation is defined). I'm afraid there can't be a guarantee of the kind you're looking for.

Comment: Any perturbation changes the distribution, so I'm surprised that you expect no change.

Comment: Actually, Chaotic map itself generate (pseudo-)random number. I was thinking adding small perturb which itself were (pseudo-)random number on the same interval could give the the result what I expected @ChristianHennig